# Wordpress htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I know that this kind of thing is a really common question, but none of the answers in other threads seem to be working for me.

I have a Wordpress site setup which currently has two domains pointing at it:

http://example.com
http://example.co.uk

I would like to setup the site so that the .com domain redirects to the .co.uk domain.  So whether you go to http://example.com or http://example.com/page-name then it'll end up at http://example.co.uk or http://example.co.uk/page-name respectively.

There is a lot of stuff going on in the .htaccess file and I'm not really sure where I should be putting the rules to do this.  I either seem to end up with a redirect loop, or it just doesn't do anything.

Full .htaccess is as follows:

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security
    # BEGIN Ban Users
        # Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Acunetix [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^binlar [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bolt\ 0 [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot\@yahoo\.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BOT\ for\ JCE [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^casper [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^checkprivacy [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^clshttp [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^cmsworldmap [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^comodo [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Default\ Browser\ 0 [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^diavol [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DIIbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^dotbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailCollector [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^extract [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^feedfinder [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FHscan [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^flicky [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^g00g1e [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^grab [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^harvest [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ia_archiver [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InternetSeer\.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^jakarta [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Java [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^kanagawa [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^kmccrew [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^libwww [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Maxthon$ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^microsoft\.url [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^miner [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla\.*Indy [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla\.*NEWT [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MSFrontPage [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^nutch [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PeoplePal [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^planetwork [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^psbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^purebot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pycurl [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Rippers\ 0 [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SeaMonkey$ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^skygrid [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^sucker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Toata\ dragostea\ mea\ pentru\ diavola [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^turnit [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^vikspider [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WPScan [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWW-Mechanize [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Yandex [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^zmeu [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AhrefsBot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CazoodleBot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} discobot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ecxi [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} GT::WWW [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} heritrix [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTP::Lite [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ia_archiver [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} id-search [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} id-search\.org [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IDBot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IRLbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2\.1 [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} LinksManager.com_bot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} linkwalker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lwp-trivial [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MFC_Tear_Sample [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Microsoft\ URL\ Control [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Missigua\ Locator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} panscient.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PECL::HTTP [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PHPCrawl [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PleaseCrawl [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SBIder [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Snoopy [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Steeler [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} URI::Fetch [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} urllib [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Web\ Sucker [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} webalta [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WebCollage [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Wells\ Search\ II [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WEP\ Search [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} zermelo [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ZyBorg [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
        # End HackRepair.com Blacklist, http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair
        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^173\.245\.56\.102$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^173\.245\.56\.102$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^173\.245\.56\.102$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^141\.101\.97\.199$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^141\.101\.97\.199$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^141\.101\.97\.199$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^108\.162\.229\.69$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^108\.162\.229\.69$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^108\.162\.229\.69$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^108\.162\.216\.83$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^108\.162\.216\.83$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^108\.162\.216\.83$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^162\.158\.255\.36$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^162\.158\.255\.36$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^162\.158\.255\.36$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^141\.101\.98\.167$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^141\.101\.98\.167$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^141\.101\.98\.167$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^108\.162\.219\.10$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^108\.162\.219\.10$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^108\.162\.219\.10$" DenyAccess

        SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^141\.101\.97\.194$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^141\.101\.97\.194$" DenyAccess
        SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^141\.101\.97\.194$" DenyAccess

        order allow,deny
        deny from env=DenyAccess
        deny from 173.245.56.102
        deny from 141.101.97.199
        deny from 108.162.229.69
        deny from 108.162.216.83
        deny from 162.158.255.36
        deny from 141.101.98.167
        deny from 108.162.219.10
        deny from 141.101.97.194
        allow from all

    # END Ban Users
    # BEGIN Tweaks
        # Rules to block access to WordPress specific files
        <files .htaccess>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>
        <files readme.html>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>
        <files readme.txt>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>
        <files install.php>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>
        <files wp-config.php>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>

        # Rules to disable XML-RPC
        <files xmlrpc.php>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </files>

        # Rules to disable directory browsing
        Options -Indexes

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On

            # Rules to protect wp-includes
            RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
            RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
            RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
            RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
            RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
            RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

            # Rules to prevent php execution in uploads
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/uploads/(.*).php(.?) - [F]

            # Rules to block unneeded HTTP methods
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

            # Rules to block suspicious URIs
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

            # Rules to block foreign characters in URLs
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F).* [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

            # Rules to help reduce spam
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)wp-comments-post\.php*
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)co.uk.* 
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment/ [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
        </IfModule>
    # END Tweaks
# END iThemes Security

# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: IMO, you can post your question here: http://www.wordpress.org/support

Comment: Your redirect code should appear as the first instructions, below `RewriteEngine on`.

Answer (score 0):

So make sure you always check that the domain you are trying to redirect is actually pointing at the site.  It was using one of those stupid iframe "redirects" so it was just never getting to my .htaccess to carry out the change.

Doh. As you were.